# Reinterpret AVC bitstream as HEVC

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.264, h.265

I understand HEVC to be a superset of AVC. HEVC allows more 'tools' to extract more compression out of a video sequence.  Is there a tool that converts an AVC stream to HEVC, completely ignoring the new HEVC features?  AVC supports interlaced frames, so that cannot be converted, but how big is the set of files that can be converted? One application could be to support 10 bit AVC decoding from a GPU that only supports 10 bit decoding for HEVC.

Comment: The bitstream syntax is different! I doubt if such a tool is possible, and if so, anyone's made one, since most players, that decode HEVC, can decode AVC.