# Decode/encode 4:2:2 with a 4:2:0 decoder/encoder

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, h.264, h.265

Similar to [Reinterpret AVC bitstream as HEVC](https://superuser.com/questions/1353195/reinterpret-avc-bitstream-as-hevc).

Some hardware codecs support 4:2:0 for 4k but not don't support 4:2:2 even for SD, with far less data.  Can you trick a codec to encode 1920x1080 4:2:2 by feeding it 1920x2160 4:2:0?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t trick it because the chroma planes are different resolution. 4:2:2 has twice as much data per chroma plane as 4:2:0. You need to rescale. It’s like trying to trick two liters of water to fit into a one liter bottle.